# Einstein bot. Use output variable from previous action as input for the next action

Tags: einstein, bots, einstein-bots

I'm struggling to get the output of a knowledge search action (string list) and feed into a call flow action (next step in the bot)

First step:

[image: Knowledge search]

Second step:

[image: Call flow with knowledge search as input]

I've tried to use in the second block the value {!knowledgeSearchResults[0].Answer__c}, but merge fields only seem to work for question/messages. How is that possible?? So frustrating, there might be a solution for this, right?